# Why do I get "No such file or directory-bash: rvm: command not found" on Terminal startup?

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rvm

When I open Terminal, I get this error before I enter a command:

```
-bash:  /Users/*username*/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source /Users/*username*/.rvm/scripts/rvm  # This loads HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory-bash: rvm: command not found
```

I can't find a way to remove this. I used `rvm implode` to uninstall RVM.

In another response on here it said to remove the first two lines from the /etc/profile file, however the lines were not there.

I'm using os x 10.8.4

Comment: look in the "`.bash_profile`" or "`.bashrc`" files in your home directory to see if it's trying to load rvm anything.

Comment: Yep, that was why. I didn't have invisible files open so I didn't catch the ".bash_profile" or the ".bashrc" in my root directory.

- Thanks!